# Xamarin.Forms Grid Overlapping

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile, grid

I want to add the icons inside the entries. I am using the Grid layout for this purpose, the icons are inside the entry but they overlap the placeholder. What might be the problem? Thanks in advance

```
       <Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
            <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="usernameEntry" Placeholder="Username" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
            <Image Source="{local:ImageResource DeliveryApplication.Logos.username.png}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>

            <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="passwordEntry" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
            <Image Source="{local:ImageResource DeliveryApplication.Logos.password.png}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>
        </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: if you place two elements in the same grid cell they will overlap each other.  Did you mean to place the Entry in a different column than the images?

Comment: @Jason hello, thank u for your time. The reason I used this method is because I saw many people using it. it worked fine when I added a left padding to the entry

Answer (score 0):

Since the entry is a custom entry I managed to add a padding to it and it worked perfectly :)